# How to count unique occurences of particular value per row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as follows:

```
df =

DATA   TYPE_1  TYPE_2  TYPE_3  EVALUATED
WW     A234    456     456     0
AA     456     123A    567     1
BB     456     123A    456     1

df = pd.DataFrame({"DATA":["WW","AA","BB"],"TYPE_1":["A234","456","456"],"TYPE_2":["456","123A","123A"],"TYPE_3":["456","567","456"],"EVALUATED":[0,1,1]})
```

I am calculating the number of times `TYPE*` apeared with `EVALUATED` equal to 0 and 1. This is the code that I am using:

```
grouped = (df.set_index('EVALUATED')
        .filter(like='TYPE_')
        .stack()
        .to_frame('TYPE')
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='TYPE', columns='EVALUATED', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
    ).reset_index()
```

I need to slightly improve this code by counting only unique occurences of `TYPE*` per row.

For example, `456` appeared two times in row 1, but it must be counted only once.

The result should be this one:

```
grouped = 

TYPE   0   1
------------
A234   1   0
456    1   2
123A   0   2
567    0   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is similar as your, only added `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1)` for remove duplicates in rows and another possible solution for fast `size` with `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
grouped = df.set_index('EVALUATED')
            .filter(like='TYPE_')
            .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1)
            .stack()
            .to_frame('TYPE')
            .reset_index()
            .groupby(['TYPE', 'EVALUATED'])
            .size()
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
print (grouped)
EVALUATED  0  1
TYPE           
123A       0  2
456        1  2
567        0  1
A234       1  0
```

Your solution:

```
grouped = (df.set_index('EVALUATED')
        .filter(like='TYPE_')
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()), axis=1) #added row for unique rows
        .stack()
        .to_frame('TYPE')
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='TYPE', columns='EVALUATED', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
    ).reset_index()

print (grouped)
EVALUATED  TYPE  0  1
0          123A  0  2
1           456  1  2
2           567  0  1
3          A234  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

***Steps:***

1) Subset columns starting with the char *`"TYPE_X"`*.

2) Construct a new `DF` by taking thier unique values across columns. Let it's new index be the contents present in *EVALUATED* column.

3) Perform `Groupby` w.r.t the index axis by specifying `level=0`. Using `apply`, `stack` the frame so that a series gets created. Take it's distinct counts using `value_counts`. `Unstack` the obtained `DF` with providing `fill_value=0`. Finally, transpose the resulting dataframe.

---

```
TYPE_cols = df.filter(like="TYPE_")
d = pd.DataFrame([pd.unique(x) for x in TYPE_cols.values], df['EVALUATED'].values)

result = d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.values.ravel()))
result.unstack(fill_value=0).T.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"TYPE"})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I do `...T.rename_axis("TYPE", axis=1)` and then do `list(result.columns), then I get `0, 1`. It means that `TYPE` is not recognized as a column name in the resulting dataframe. How to fix it?